# What does "How do you like it?" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, american-english

A friend of mine, who was born, raised, and still lives on Long Island, had asked me *How do you like it?* when I ate something she prepared. I always replied *I like it.* or *It's very good.* as if the question were *Do you like it?*

Is that what I was asked, or is *How do you like it?* different from *Do you like it?* or *Do you enjoy it?* in this context?

I am asking because, in Italian, asking *How do you like it?* to mean *Do you like it?* would be unusual.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a different meaning; it's just another way of saying 'What do you think of it?'

Comment: *How do you like it?* is not always comparable to *Do you like it?* - you can answer the latter with "Yes/No", but you can't say "Yes/No" in response to the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is functionally the same as "Do you like it?",  except it is more converstional.

Saying "Do you like it?" can be replied with "Yes", which is ends the conversation. But you can't answer "Yes" to "How do you like it?" You are expected to say a bit more: "I like it very much." or "I like the carrots, but the sauce is too salty for me".  Saying "How do you like it?" is intended to start the conversation, not end it.

Comment: Whoops... I am sorry: I forgot to accept this answer.

Comment: Just to explain more why I was puzzled about *How do you like it?*: In Italian, I would not start a conversation with *How do you like it?* To start a conversation, I would say *Do you like it?* and the other person could also answer by saying how it likes it better (*I like it much, but I would have preferred it less salty.*) I could ask *How do you like it?* to somebody who said he didn't like something. (*I don't like starting my days this way.* *How do you like starting your days?*)